Android app development - Enable/Disable automatic focus on key press of external/physical keyboard
When trying to process input outside of a specific input field, Android always puts a focus on the first element of the currently selected or focused view (also highlighted with color). This is not only reproducible inside a custom developed app, but also perceivable in system settings.
Main question: How can this behavior be enabled or disabled, either globally or on app side?
How to to reproduce: Just connect a Bluetooth or wired keyboard to your Android device, go to system settings, scroll a little down, and hit a numeric or alphabetic key. Boom. The first element that is visible to the user is automatically focused.

Does this answer your question? Is this statement "Although Android gives focus to the first text field in your layout when the activity starts" still valid?

@Risto Thanks for the linkage, but sadly, that does not answer my question. I am not talking about initial focus, and I do not want to disable focusability/accessibility at all. I rather would like to disable the functionality that leads to the fact that in a list / scroll / recycler view the first element in sight of the current view is focussed on a keypress of an external keyboard. Maybe this is a core feature of Android and cannot be disabled at all?
